# How do I resize my canvas with my elements in it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, resize

## Background Information

I'm currently working on a project and I want the background to be a blank canvas with balls bouncing off the walls.

I've managed so far, but I've come across a problem.
Whenever I resize my browser window, neither my canvas or the balls in it follow through. I have no clue what I'm doing wrong.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/brinobre/pen/bGdGjjr)

## Code

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#responsive-canvas')

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

let c = canvas.getContext('2d');

function Circle(x, y, dx, dy, radius, colour) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.dx = dx;
  this.dy = dy;
  this.radius = radius;
  this.colour = colour;


  this.draw = function() {

    this.getNewColour = function() {
      let symbols, colour;

      symbols = "0123456789ABCDEF";

      colour = "#";

      for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        colour += symbols[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
      }
      c.strokeStyle = colour;
      c.fillStyle = colour;
    }
    this.getNewColour();


    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.radius = radius;
    //this.getNewColour().colour = colour;

    c.beginPath();
    c.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    //  c.strokeStyle = 'blue';
    c.stroke();
    //c.fill();
  }

  this.update = function() {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.dx = dx;
    this.dy = dy;
    this.radius = radius;

    if (x + radius > innerWidth || x - radius < 0) {
      dx = -dx;
    }

    if (y + radius > innerHeight || y - radius < 0) {
      dy = -dy;
    }
    x += dx;
    y += dy;

    this.draw();
  }
}

let circleArr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 23; i++) {

  let radius = 50;
  let x = Math.random() * (innerWidth - radius * 2) + radius;
  let y = Math.random() * (innerHeight - radius * 2) + radius;
  let dx = (Math.random() - 0.5);
  let dy = (Math.random() - 0.5);

  circleArr.push(new Circle(x, y, dx, dy, radius));
};




function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  c.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight)

  for (var i = 0; i < circleArr.length; i++) {
    circleArr[i].update();
  }
};



animate();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* BODY
*/

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/css/style.css">

  <body>
    <canvas id="responsive-canvas"></canvas>
  </body>
  <script src="js/canvas.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you must fix your collision logic, then you can safely change the canvas size as needed.

### Always resolve the collisions fully.

An unresolved collision means that your sim is in an impossible state (eg ball inside a wall). From that point the following states will be meaning less.

### Fix

The reason why the balls move out of the canvas is because you are not moving them back onto the canvas if they are outside.

Also when you change the ball direction when it hits the side you do not ensure that the direction is the correct sign.

```
    // if the dx = 1 and x > innerWidth + 1000 then dx becomes -1
    // Next tine x is still > innerWidth + 1000 and you flip the sign of dx again to 1,
    // Then dx to -1 and so on. You never move the ball 
    if(x + radius > innerWidth || x - radius < 0) {
        dx = -dx;  
    }
```

Be systematic in the collision testing so that when the playfield (canvas) changes size you don't get unexpected results

When you update, first move then check for collisions. If there is a collision, move the ball again to ensure not magic ball in wall thing happening.

```
update() {
    this.x += this.dx;
    this.y += this.dy;
    if (this.x < this.radius) {
        this.x = this.radius;
        this.dx = Math.abs(this.dx);
    }
    if (this.y < this.radius) {
        this.y = this.radius;
        this.dy = Math.abs(this.dy);
    }
    if (this.x > ctx.canvas.width - this.radius) {
        this.x = ctx.canvas.width - this.radius;
        this.dx = -Math.abs(this.dx);
    }
    if (this.y > ctx.canvas.height - this.radius) {
        this.y = ctx.canvas.height - this.radius;
        this.dy = -Math.abs(this.dy);
    }
}
```

### Resize the canvas

With the collision problem solved you can now change the canvas size whenever you need to. One way is to do it inside the animate function.

If the canvas size does not match the page size change the canvas size to match.

```
function animate () {
    if (ctx.canvas.width !== innerWidth || ctx.canvas.height !== innerHeight) {
        ctx.canvas.width = innerWidth;
        ctx.canvas.height = innerHeight;
    } else {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height)
    }

    // ... do stuff

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

**Note** that changing the canvas size also clears the canvas, that is why the clear is on the `else` clause.

### Copy paste demo

There were many bad points in the code. You can copy paste the snippet below into code pen or use the information above to modify your code in your style.

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('#responsive-canvas')

canvas.width = innerWidth;
canvas.height = innerHeight;

// Set constants in one place so you can make changes quickly and easily
const DEFAULT_RADIUS = 50;
const MAX_SPEED = 5;
const CIRCLE_COUNT = 100;
Math.TAU = Math.PI * 2

// Use function to do repetitive code
Math.rand = (min, max) => Math.random() * (max - min) + min;  // 
function randomHexColor() { 
    return "#" + ((Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF | 0).toString(16).padStart(6,"0"));
}

// pulral names for arrays and variables that do not change should be constants
const circles = [];
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

requestAnimationFrame(animate); // start frame renderer with a request, dont call it directly



function Circle( // using default params to set random values
        radius = Math.rand(DEFAULT_RADIUS/4, DEFAULT_RADIUS), // radius must be first argument as its used to set random x, and y
        x = Math.rand(radius, ctx.canvas.width - radius), 
        y = Math.rand(radius, ctx.canvas.height - radius),
        dx = Math.rand(-MAX_SPEED, MAX_SPEED),
        dy = Math.rand(-MAX_SPEED, MAX_SPEED),
        colour = randomHexColor()
    ) {

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.dx = dx;
    this.dy = dy;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.colour = colour;
}
// Define Circle functions as prototype outside the function Circle (runs faster)
Circle.prototype = {
    draw() {
        ctx.strokeStyle = ctx.fillStyle = this.colour; 
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.TAU);
        ctx.stroke();
    },
    update() {
        this.x += this.dx;
        this.y += this.dy;
        if (this.x < this.radius) {
            this.x = this.radius;
            this.dx = Math.abs(this.dx);
        }
        if (this.y < this.radius) {
            this.y = this.radius;
            this.dy = Math.abs(this.dy);
        }
        if (this.x > ctx.canvas.width - this.radius) {
            this.x = ctx.canvas.width - this.radius;
            this.dx = -Math.abs(this.dx);
        }
        if (this.y > ctx.canvas.height - this.radius) {
            this.y = ctx.canvas.height - this.radius;
            this.dy = -Math.abs(this.dy);
        }
    }
};
for (let i = 0; i < CIRCLE_COUNT; i++) { circles.push(new Circle()) } 
function animate () {
    if (ctx.canvas.width !== innerWidth || ctx.canvas.height !== innerHeight) {
        ctx.canvas.width = innerWidth;
        ctx.canvas.height = innerHeight;
    } else {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height)
    }

    // use for of loop (saves having to mess with index)
    for (const circle of circles) {
            circle.update(); // seperate update and draw
            circle.draw()
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I know my code was messy. I checked out your code snippet on the same codepen I linked before and I'm curious why your ```randomHexColour``` function doesnt work? I'm new to ES6 and I didn't really understand the syntax that well. Further more I tried using my own ```getNewColour ``` function instead by implementing it into your code. It worked fairly well except for the fact all the balls turn black after i resize the window. How do I solve this? The codepen Is updated. Again, I'm fairly new to webdevelopment and this is my first canvas. I appreciate the help. Cheers

Comment: @Kemura Oh so sorry about the color function I forgot to round the random value and most important convert the value to Hex with `Number.toString(16)` the correct version is . `return "#" + (Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF |  0).toString(16).padStart(6,"0");`. I will add it to the answer. When you resize the canvas it resets its state (styles default to black). Make sure you set `ctx.strokeStyle` and or `ctx.fillStyle` to the colour you want before rendering the circle.

Answer (score 2):

you can use 
`ctx.scale(x,y);`
to scale everything on the canvas by the given factor, the X and Y are scalling on X and Y axis respectively.

You might want to reset the canvas using
`ctx.resetTransform()` or `ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);`
Then draw your background from 0,0 to canvas.width and canvas.height
Then draw everything (all of the circles) and finally set the scalling to your desired value.

Comment: Warning `resetTransform` is experimental technology and not fully supported by all browsers. Use alternate method to safely reset transform as demonstrated in this answer with `setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);`

Answer (score 1):

If you want the width and height to change, you just need to add the width and height in the same CSS area that the `{border-box} is in.

but if you want to make the images inside it to not be stretched, you would need to access the heigh specifically in the canvas using the above comments methods.

Preferably using:

```
width:() => document.documentElement.clientWidth
```